# POST List of Objects in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, post

I can't post list of objects (Count is unknown) from view to Controller. I worked something out and here what I do with JS. I have a button to add 2 inputs and a remove button beside that row of 2 inputs. each of the inputs has the name of the Model like Product.Features[0].TitleName and Product.Features[0].Value

everything works fine but the problem is that if we have 3 inputs and user click on the remove button of index 1, then after posting the form, just index 0 will post and ignore index 2!

How can I do something to have inputs as many as user wants and has the ability to remove in any order.

My Model is a product model that has many things and has List of ProductFeatures Model:

```
public class ProductFeature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string TitleName { get; set; }
    public required string Value { get; set; }
}
```

my HTML :

```
<div class="accordion-body w-50">
    <div id="features" class="form-group">
    </div>
    <input id="cmdAdd1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="افزودن ویژگی" />
</div>
```

and here is the JS:

```
var itemCount = 0;
const removedItems = [];

$('#cmdAdd1').click(function () { addNewFeature(); });

function addNewFeature() {
// Add new line with text field and button
    if (removedItems.length == 0) {
        var newItem = ' <div id="item' + itemCount + '" class="input-group mb-2">';
        newItem += '<input id="title' + itemCount + '" name="Product.ProductFeatures[' + itemCount + '].TitleName" placeholder="عنوان" class="form-control" type="text"/>';
        newItem += '<input id="value' + itemCount + '" name="Product.ProductFeatures[' + itemCount + '].Value" placeholder="مقدار" class="form-control" type="text"/>';
        newItem += '<input id="cmdAdd' + itemCount + '" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="حذف ویژگی"></input>';
        newItem += "</div>";

        $('#features').append(newItem);
        var thisItem = itemCount;
        $('#cmdAdd' + itemCount).click(function () { removeItem(thisItem); });
        itemCount++;
    }
    else {
        var id = removedItems[0];
        var newItem = ' <div id="item' + id + '" class="input-group mb-2">';
        newItem += '<input id="title' + id + '" name="Product.ProductFeatures[' + id + '].TitleName" placeholder="عنوان" class="form-control" type="text"/>';
        newItem += '<input id="value' + id + '" name="Product.ProductFeatures[' + id + '].Value" placeholder="مقدار" class="form-control" type="text"/>';
        newItem += '<input id="cmdAdd' + id + '" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="حذف ویژگی"></input>';
        newItem += "</div>";

        $('#features').append(newItem);
        thisItem = id;
        $('#cmdAdd' + id).click(function () { removeItem(thisItem); });
        removedItems.splice(0, 1);
    }
}

function removeItem(i) {
    $('#item' + i).remove();
    removedItems.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding an image or video, you should put your code along with the description and errors you have  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh Edited. Thanks

Comment: @AliJebali _"clearly you can see everything"_ - **No, I can't**, because I'm not going to watch your video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing seems related to how the items are indexed when adding and removing them dynamically in your JavaScript code. When an item is removed, the array "**removedItems**" keeps track of removed indexes, but it doesn't rearrange the indexes of the existing items, causing a mismatch between the indexes in the form data and the actual items on the page.

One way to solve this issue is to re-index the input fields' names when an item is removed.

```js
var itemCount = 0;

$('#cmdAdd1').click(function () { addNewFeature(); });

function addNewFeature() {
    var newItem = '<div id="item' + itemCount + '" class="input-group mb-2">';
    newItem += '<input id="title' + itemCount + '" name="Product.ProductFeatures[' + itemCount + '].TitleName" placeholder="عنوان" class="form-control" type="text"/>';
    newItem += '<input id="value' + itemCount + '" name="Product.ProductFeatures[' + itemCount + '].Value" placeholder="مقدار" class="form-control" type="text"/>';
    newItem += '<input id="cmdAdd' + itemCount + '" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="حذف ویژگی"></input>';
    newItem += '</div>';

    $('#features').append(newItem);
    var thisItem = itemCount;
    $('#cmdAdd' + itemCount).click(function () { removeItem(thisItem); });
    itemCount++;
}

function removeItem(i) {
    $('#item' + i).remove();
    // Re-index the remaining items
    reIndexItems();
}

function reIndexItems() {
    var items = $('#features').children();
    items.each(function (index) {
        var id = 'item' + index;
        $(this).attr('id', id);
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
            var inputName = 'Product.ProductFeatures[' + index + '].' + $(this).attr('name').split('.')[2];
            $(this).attr('name', inputName);
        });
        $(this).find('input[type=button]').attr('onclick', 'removeItem(' + index + ')');
    });
}
```

This code should dynamically adjust the indexes of the remaining items whenever one is removed, ensuring that all the indexes are aligned properly when the form is submitted.